# Node.JS - Facebook API - Get feed but exclude system generated dummy statuses

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all contents published by a person on his own facebook wall, that includes images, videos, text or simply status update.

I have tried the following API with Node.JS but all resulted in different problems. The API calls either miss contents or return extra system generated data such as "User A has become friends with User B", or "User has liked a picture".

Let me explain this by some examples:

1. Url: https://graph.facebook.com/barackobama/statuses. The API call returns a json document with last update_time = "2013-07-01T15:08:15+0000", but in fact [Obama's page](https://www.facebook.com/barackobama?fref=ts) has much more recent update than this.
2. Url: https://graph.facebook.com/random.things.16/posts. The API call returns empty JSON array, while the actual [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/random.things.16?fref=ts) contains some pictures. If you try this API call on some other users, you may also likely to get back system generated statuses as mentioned above.
3. Url: https://graph.facebook.com/CwcvilleGuardian/feed. Similar issue as posts API.

Note that for system generated statues like "User has liked a picture". I'd love to have one of the following ways to handle them:

1. Exclude it from results if some parameters can be applied on the API call.
2. Resolve that "a picture" so that we can know which picture the user has liked. Note that practically user can like a video, a link, a post, a comment or something else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Facebook stopped calling things a purely a "Status" programmaticly a long time ago. Now everything is a "Post" of different type "Link, Status, Photo, or Video".  So you if you want all the Posts you need to call

   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/barackobama/posts
2. The object you are attempting to get is a "User" type account. You can not query based on a Username you have to use an App Scoped User ID (a number). The thing you are looking at does "look" like a "page" but who ever set it up broke Facebook's TOS because it is registered as a "user" when it really a "page". That being said you'll have to get an App Scoped User ID in order to even get "public" info about a user. You don't need an App Scoped ID to get public info about a page. In order to get an app scoped user id a user will have give permission to your app to do so, even to get the public info.
3. Same issue as 2, however this is a User account so no TOS violations here. Here you have used "Feed" instead of "Posts". "Posts" are a list of everything the Users as posted to their own timeline. "Feed" is an aggregation of what the user has posted as well as what others have posted to the user's timeline.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. Testing out the implementation now, will mark later after I settle it.